# How to stop Mobile chrome from discarding/reloading tabs?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile

I have been listening to some old radio shows on an archive website (radioechos) on my phone but if I pause what I am listening to and leave my phone for too long then when I return the tab has refreshed and I have lost my place in the show

I have managed to find many ways to stop chrome from doing such things on desktop but none for mobile chrome (chrome://discards/ does not appear to exist for mobile)

edit: crap managed to post on entirely the wrong website, sorry

Comment: Reminder that StackOverflow is for programming questions. End user/power user questions about Android should be directed to: https://android.stackexchange.com/